# need programming video card

Tags: graphics-cards, development, 4k

I just got a Dell 8900 and would like to get a graphics card. The card would have to be able to drive two monitors (2 x 2k) or one 4K monitor. I never play games - just do development work using Visual Studio and Eclipse and occasionally watch films on my monitors. What card would be good enough for this?
I am interested in spending $150-250. The built in graphics cannot support a 4K monitor.

Comment: Most current-generation cards will work.  Do you have any requirements such as monitor connection type?

Comment: What's your price range? How much power do you want?

Comment: there is no such thing as a "programming" video card.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why this question is being downvoted, seems reasonable, and I am in the market for something like this myself. I like the look of the MSI GTX 960. Can drive multiple 4k monitors, has 3xDP, 1xHDMI and 1xDVI-D outputs and is apparently very quiet - the fans can be stopped completely in "silent mode" which should be enough for non-gaming use.

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/msi-geforce-gtx-960-gaming-2g,review-33260.html

Comment: *"Don't know why this question is being downvoted"* - This question is very general and hard to objectively answer. The OP didn't specify the price range (the 960 is at 200USD IIRC), he didn't specify what his PSU can actually supply (the 960 needs 120W IIRC), the OP didn't clarify which ports he needs (HDMI 2? HDMI 2.0b? DP 1.4? DP 1.2?). This overall lack of requirements means a _lot_ of cards will fit the description, especially as modern integrated graphics already would suffice likely.